# Why won't my game run when higher values are entered?

Tags: python

I am making a text based game in python 3.4 that has to do a lot of calculating. My problem is that when I enter a higher value for my game, it doesn't give any output or error.

This code gets the input from a user and makes it into a tuple.

```
def getCoords():
    mapdata = []
    coords = input('Enter 2 numbers without a space from 11 - 99>')
    coords = tuple(coords)
    coords = tuple(map(int, coords)) 
    for x in range(1, 10):
        for y in range(1, 10):
            mapdata.append((x,y))
    while coords not in mapdata:
        print('Invalid target.')
        coords = input('Enter 2 numbers without a space from 11 - 99>')
        coords = tuple(coords)
        coords = tuple(map(int, coords))
    return coords
```

This tuple is passed to this function to calculate the enemies.

```
def getEnemy(coords):
    place = coords[0]
    level = coords[1]
    elbm = level * level * 500
    emino = level * level * 300
    egiant = level * level * 150
    enemy = [elbm, emino, egiant]
    p = 0
    for i in etroops:
        etroops[p] = enemy[p]
        p =+ 1
```

Then this is passed to this function.

```
def battle():
    #setup attacker
    lbmhealth = troops[0] * lbmstats[0]
    minohealth = troops[1] * minostats[0]
    gianthealth = troops[2] * giantstats[0]
    #setup defender
    elbmhealth = etroops [0] * lbmstats[0]
    eminohealth = etroops[1] * minostats[0]
    egianthealth = etroops[2] * giantstats[0]
    #battle calculate
    turn = getTurn()
    game = 1
    while game == 1:
        while turn == 1:
            if elbmhealth > 0:
                p = 0
                for i in troops:
                    if i > 0:
                        elbmhealth = elbmhealth - int(troops[p] * allstats[p][1] / allstats[0][2])
                        etroops[0] = int(elbmhealth / lbmstats[0])
                        if etroops[0] < 0:
                            etroops[0] = 0
                        p += 1
```

Calls to other functions.

```
def setup():
    coords = getCoords()
    enemydata = getEnemy(coords)
    battle()

setup()
```

This is the beginning of my program.

```
import random

#variables
lbm = 5000
mino = 4000
giant = 500
troops = []
troops.extend([lbm, mino, giant])
etroops = [0, 0, 0]

#troops stats
lbmstats = [100, 200, 50, 50,50]
minostats = [300, 100, 150, 70, 200]
giantstats = [800, 150, 400, 25, 650]
allstats = [lbmstats, minostats, giantstats]
```

This just returns 1 or 2 to determine who's turn it is.

```
def getTurn():
    attackerspd = 0
    defenderspd = 0
    p = 0
    for i in troops:
        attackerspd = attackerspd + allstats[p][4] * troops[p]
        p += 1
        if p == 2:
        p = 0
    for i in troops:
        defenderspd = defenderspd + allstats[p][4] * etroops[p]
        p += 1
        if p == 2:
            p = 0
    if attackerspd > defenderspd:
        turn = 1
    elif defenderspd > attackerspd:
        turn = 0
    else:
        turn = random.randint(0, 1)
    return turn
```

When I run the program, It asks for my input. When I input 11 or 12, the program works fine. Any higher and the program doesnt respond. How do I make my program run for higher values?

Comment: Your program, when run, calls `getCoords`?

Comment: Yes. Should I put more code?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please I wasn't able to recreate the program hanging

Comment: Neither of these variables are defined: `troops[0] * lbmstats[0]`

Comment: You set `enemydata = getEnemy(coords)` but `getEnemy` doesn't return anything. Also the variable `place`, set to the first of the `coords`, is never used in the code you have shown.

Comment: Just added the other stuff. The variable place will be used later on. The function getEnemy calculates the amount of enemies and adds it to a list that is outside of the function.

Comment: Will remove variable enemydata. I had made big changes to my code and left that behind. Thanks Stuart.

Comment: `battle()` gets stuck in an infinite loop because there is nothing to change `turn` or `game` or to return from the function. This happens regardless of the value entered.

Comment: I have put print() in there to debug it.

Comment: Also, when the 2nd coord you enter is 0, 1, or 2, `turn` is always 0. The programme enters the loop `while game == 1 ...`, is stuck and never does anything else. If it is 3-9 then `turn` is always 1, and the programme enters the 2nd loop `while turn == 1`; but still gets stuck because there is no way of exiting that loop.

Comment: I found my problem. In the block while turn ==1: the program never entered this loop because turn was == 0.

Comment: Okay, but the code as copied here won't work in any case. Good luck!

Comment: In the block while turn == 1, the program never entered this loop because turn was == 0. getCoords() returned 0 when a larger value was entered for coords because defenderspd was larger than attacker speed. Thanks for the help. Would have been stuck on this forever if you didn't point out the infinite loop part.

Comment: I still have a lot to do before it is done. Thanks for the help.